# Print taxonomy information based on the link that is clicked

Tags: taxonomy-terms, hooks, theming, routes

Lets say I have a taxonomy called fruits. I have 3 links on my front page and the href-s are:

fruits/bananas
fruits/oranges
fruits/apples

I made a custom module to do this but I am not really sure what to do next...

```
function mymodyle_menu() {
    $items['fuits/%'] = array(
      'page callback' => 'mymodule_fruits',
      'access callback' => TRUE
    );
    return $items;
  }

  function mymodule_fruits() {
  //what to do?
}
```

I also have a template file for them. How to do this?

Comment: Do you just want to have a custom link for the taxonomy page or are you trying to accomplish something else?

Comment: I didn`t get your question well, but if you mean you want to display some information about the taxonomy that is just clicked, or print some related taxonomies you can use views contextual filter.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a custom pattern for the URL then you are better of with [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module

Once you enable the module if you go to Admin -> URL Alias you will get a new TAB Pattern. In that you can define the pattern that you want to give to the taxonomy page. By default it would be `[term:vocabulary]/[term:name]`

So if your vocabulary name is **fruits** and your term name is **apples** then the url will automatically be turned into fruits/apples

After you enable the module you might have to do Bulk Update from URL aliases for the urls to take effect.

If the requirement is to add more information regarding the taxonomy terms or nodes with in the taxonomy term then you should use the [views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module

If you are simply trying to learn the how things work with in drupal then you should check the [examples](http://drupal.org/project/examples) module it has got all sorts of modules to get you started with.